# drop last column of a dataframe using spark-scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

i have a dataframe without header name. I want to drop last column records but without passing column name .
Is there any way of doing this?

```
df.drop("colname")
```

instead of passing column name here how can i drop last column from the dataframe.

Answer (score 3):

Use the same API while resolving the last column using `df.schema`:

```
df.drop(df.schema.last.name)
```

Comment: or even shorter : `df.drop(df.columns.last)`

Comment: any idea how to do it in pyspark

Comment: Pyspark : df.drop(df.columns[-1])

Comment: Actually, I needed `.schema.last.name`. Without `.name` at the end there, it gave an overloaded method error (spark 2.4.4).

Answer (score 0):

another option in scala

`df.drop(df.columns(df.columns.length -1))` ***for dropping last column***

`df.drop(df.columns(0))` ***for dropping first column***

Here is complete Example :

```
  val mycsv =
    """
      ||TemperatureF|Date|timestamp|MinTemp|MaxTemp|
      ||        28.0| 01/01/2000 6:53 AM|946709580|   28.0|   37.4|
      ||        28.0| 01/01/2000 7:53 AM|946713180|   28.0|   37.4|
      ||        28.0| 01/01/2000 8:53 AM|946716780|   28.0|   37.4|
      ||        30.2|01/01/2000 10:24 PM|946765440|   30.2|   37.4|
      ||        30.9|01/01/2000 10:53 PM|946767180|   30.9|   37.4|
      ||        37.4| 01/02/2000 4:39 AM|946787940|   28.0|   37.4|
      ||        36.0| 01/02/2000 4:53 AM|946788780|   28.0|   36.0|
      ||        36.0| 01/02/2000 5:53 AM|946792380|   28.0|   36.0|
    """.stripMargin('|').lines.toList.toDS()
  val df = spark.read.option("header", true).option("sep", "|").option("inferSchema", true).csv(mycsv)
  println("original schema with first and last extra columns")
  df.printSchema

  val afterfirstAndLastDF =  df
    .drop(df.columns(df.columns.length - 1)) // drop last column
    .drop(df.columns(0)) // drop first column
  afterfirstAndLastDF.show()
  afterfirstAndLastDF.printSchema
```

Result :

```
original schema with first and last extra columns
root
 |-- _c0: string (nullable = true)
 |-- TemperatureF: double (nullable = true)
 |-- Date: string (nullable = true)
 |-- timestamp: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- MinTemp: double (nullable = true)
 |-- MaxTemp: double (nullable = true)
 |-- _c6: string (nullable = true)

+------------+-------------------+---------+-------+-------+
|TemperatureF|               Date|timestamp|MinTemp|MaxTemp|
+------------+-------------------+---------+-------+-------+
|        28.0| 01/01/2000 6:53 AM|946709580|   28.0|   37.4|
|        28.0| 01/01/2000 7:53 AM|946713180|   28.0|   37.4|
|        28.0| 01/01/2000 8:53 AM|946716780|   28.0|   37.4|
|        30.2|01/01/2000 10:24 PM|946765440|   30.2|   37.4|
|        30.9|01/01/2000 10:53 PM|946767180|   30.9|   37.4|
|        37.4| 01/02/2000 4:39 AM|946787940|   28.0|   37.4|
|        36.0| 01/02/2000 4:53 AM|946788780|   28.0|   36.0|
|        36.0| 01/02/2000 5:53 AM|946792380|   28.0|   36.0|
+------------+-------------------+---------+-------+-------+

root
 |-- TemperatureF: double (nullable = true)
 |-- Date: string (nullable = true)
 |-- timestamp: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- MinTemp: double (nullable = true)
 |-- MaxTemp: double (nullable = true)
```